# TortoiseSVN adding junk to root repo directory on checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am running a hybrid workplace with windows and linux clients, with an svn server on a CentOS machine.

Recently, when windows users are checking out our project repo, the following files get added to the root repo directory:

```
Desktop.ini
README.txt
conf
db
format
hooks
locks
svn.ico
```

I would prefer to keep the root directory tidy, so I have to go in and do an `svn merge -c ...` to revert the changes.  It's quite confusing, as the users aren't making any commits, yet there are changes to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [revision history log](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html). Someone has committed a repository database into your repository. These directories and files belong to a repository database that usually resides on server side.

Comment: Yes, I checked the log.  This was how I identified the user that commited the change.  The problem is that this happened at checkout, without the user actually performing a commit.

Comment: @Macattack278 rollback the invalid commit and ask the users to update their working copies. Then ask them to check their modifications before committing. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html